# Splitting the full name and writing it to another table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, split

I have a table, say **A**, in which there is a column *FULLNAME*. Values stored under this column are in the format of "surname name middle_name" (with one space between each). And I have another table **B**, in which I have columns *SURNAME*, *NAME* and *MIDDLENAME*. What would be the best way to take all of the *FULLNAME* cells from the table **A**, split them accordingly and insert them into the table **B**?

Thanks

Comment: Add your tables structures, it helps understanding your question. Also, wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL...? What have you tried? Post some working queries, does not matter if the result is incorrect, is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the solution. Also if possible post some test data. You can use [SQL Fiddle online tool](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) to provide all this information.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server. Also, I tried looking at some user-defined functions like described here http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/split-name.aspx, but I am kinda new to all of this (which you can obviously tell), and have little notion about these.

Comment: write fullname example ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine functions for searching an occurence in a string (which return normally its index) with the Substring function, besides you will need the Left and Right functions

For example in SQL Server you will find the functions:

[CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

[SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

[LEFT ( character_expression , integer_expression )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx)

[RIGHT ( character_expression , integer_expression )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx)

STEPS:

1. Use the LEFT to get the 1st word (integer_expression = index of 1st
   Emtpy space)
2. Use Substring to get the middle word (start is the index of 1st
   Emtpy space + 1 , length is the entire length - the second index of
   the emtpy space, use the startlocation to search the second occurence which should be the first occurence +1)
3. Use the right function to get the last word similar to step 1

Notice that if you have any names including empty spaces in the middle (example a first name like anna maria) this wouldnt work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This query will spilt your string.

```
select left(FULLNAME,CHARINDEX(' ',FULLNAME)), SUBSTRING(FULLNAME,CHARINDEX(' ',name)+1,len(FULLNAME)) from tableA
```